# Print staments are lost when execute a python file from subprocess.call method

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a Python code where I am executing a command to run another python file by using subprocess.call() method.
The file I execute inside the subprocess.call() has some print statements in it but those statements are not printed on the console when I run this code.
Is there a way I can get them printed on the console ? Everything works fine when I execute this file standalone and not through the subprocess.call().
If I redirect the output of this command to a file then it gets printed in the file, but could not find a way to see it on console at runtime.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Double check that you really need to use subprocess to run a python program and can't just import it. There are many reasons to do this way, and it will most likely solve your problem either

Comment: Please [edit] to include your current code.

Answer (score 1):

subprocess call has default params: `stdout=None, stderr=None` which you need to configure or use `capture_output=True`, see following docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [subprocess.PIPE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE):

```
p = subprocess.call(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _ = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

(Written in the browser, but should work)

Btw, it's hard to understand your problem and suggest a solution when you don't provide any code (neither which you run with subprocess nor which uses it). Please, add it to get more specific and/or relevant answers

Comment: @Ashgonline, did this help?